# How to reuse a form in a single page application

Tags: javascript, html, forms

The following let's me handle a form's submit action with Javascript.

When the form is submitted, I'd like to be able to hide it, then reuse it later. Unfortunately, this code has some kind of state that prevents the submit action being executed more than once.

How can I reset the magic hidden state?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="console.log('Submitted'); return false;">
    Your Name <br/>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Give your form a name and id.  Wrap it in a DIV you can hide.  Use Javascript to handle how it behaves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @durbnpoisn suggested:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>

    <script>
       function myFunction(container) {
            console.log('myFunction');
            var inputs = container.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for(i = 0;i < inputs.length; i++) {
                console.log(i+ ": "+inputs[i].outerHTML);
            }
            container.style.visibility = "hidden";
            return false;
        };

       function reset() {
            form1container.style.visibility = "visible";
            form2container.style.visibility = "visible";
            return false;
       };

    </script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="form1container">
    <form action="" method="" onsubmit="">
        Your Name <br/>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name1"/>
        <input id="submitButton1" onclick="myFunction(form1container, form1container.form);" type="button"
               value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>

<div id="form2container">
    <form action="" method="" onsubmit="">
        Your Name <br/>
        <input type="text" name="name"/>
        <input id="submitButton2" onclick="myFunction(form2container);" type="button"
               value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>

<input id="button3" onclick="reset();" type="button" value="Reveal">


</body>
</html>
```